Handling EOS Messages in GStreamer and Stopping Egress in Go Application
I'm working on a Go application that uses GStreamer for handling media streams and a custom egress service to manage outgoing streams. I'm facing issues when the GStreamer pipeline receives an EOS (End of Stream) message. I want to stop the egress process gracefully upon receiving this EOS message but I'm encountering some problems.issue happen when i disconnect the stream, if i send stop egress it works fine
Here's a snippet of the logs showing the warnings and errors:
go
2024-07-12T14:55:28.876Z        DEBUG   logger/logger.go:284    HealthCheck SendRequest method Called   {"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK"}
2024-07-12T14:55:33.923Z        DEBUG   egress  [gst warning] gst_h264_parser_parse_slice_hdr: value for 'slice->slice_qp_delta' not in allowed range. value: 88, range -87-77        {"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK", "caller": "../gst-libs/gst/codecparsers/gsth264parser.c:2585"}
2024-07-12T14:55:33.923Z        DEBUG   egress  [gst warning] gst_h264_parser_parse_slice_hdr: error parsing "Slice header"     {"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK", "caller": "../gst-libs/gst/codecparsers/gsth264parser.c:2619"}

 
2024-07-12T14:55:33.924Z        DEBUG   egress  [gst warning] gst_pad_query_accept_caps_default: caps: video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, width=(int)2, height=(int)2, framerate=(fraction)25/1, coded-picture-structure=(string)frame, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)baseline, level=(string)3.1, codec_data=(buffer)0142c01fffe200142742c01f898a300a00b74d408080ad878442334000186742c01f0fd91f888884000003000400000300c83c60c9200100066887cb83cb20 were not compatible with: EMPTY {"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK", "caller": "../gst/gstpad.c:3266", "object": "video_0"}
2024-07-12T14:55:33.924Z        DEBUG   egress  [gst warning] pre_eventfunc_check: caps video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, width=(int)2, height=(int)2, framerate=(fraction)25/1, coded-picture-structure=(string)frame, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)baseline, level=(string)3.1, codec_data=(buffer)0142c01fffe200142742c01f898a300a00b74d408080ad878442334000186742c01f0fd91f888884000003000400000300c83c60c9200100066887cb83cb20 not accepted   {"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK", "caller": "../gst/gstpad.c:5819", "object": "video"}
2024-07-12T14:55:33.924Z        INFO    egress  source/sdk.go:455       removing video writer   {"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK"}
2024-07-12T14:55:33.924Z        DEBUG   egress  sdk/appwriter.go:203    draining        {"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK", "trackID": "TR_VCcoyq66v5r79s", "kind": "video"}
DRAING-1
2024-07-12T14:55:33.924Z        DEBUG   egress  [gst warning] gst_pad_query_accept_caps_default: caps: video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, width=(int)2, height=(int)2, framerate=(fraction)25/1, coded-picture-structure=(string)frame, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)baseline, level=(string)3.1, codec_data=(buffer)0142c01fffe200142742c01f898a300a00b74d408080ad878442334000186742c01f0fd91f888884000003000400000300c83c60c9200100066887cb83cb20 were not compatible with: EMPTY {"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK", "caller": "../gst/gstpad.c:3266", "object": "video_0"}
2024-07-12T14:55:33.924Z        DEBUG   egress  [gst warning] pre_eventfunc_check: caps video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, width=(int)2, height=(int)2, framerate=(fraction)25/1, coded-picture-structure=(string)frame, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)baseline, level=(string)3.1, codec_data=(buffer)0142c01fffe200142742c01f898a300a00b74d408080ad878442334000186742c01f0fd91f888884000003000400000300c83c60c9200100066887cb83cb20 not accepted   {"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK", "caller": "../gst/gstpad.c:5819", "object": "video"}
2024-07-12T14:55:33.924Z        DEBUG   egress  [gst warning] gst_pad_query_accept_caps_default: caps: video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, width=(int)2, height=(int)2, framerate=(fraction)25/1, coded-picture-structure=(string)frame, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)baseline, level=(string)3.1, codec_data=(buffer)0142c01fffe200142742c01f898a300a00b74d408080ad878442334000186742c01f0fd91f888884000003000400000300c83c60c9200100066887cb83cb20 were not compatible with: EMPTY {"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK", "caller": "../gst/gstpad.c:3266", "object": "video_0"}
2024-07-12T14:55:33.924Z        DEBUG   egress  [gst warning] pre_eventfunc_check: caps video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, width=(int)2, height=(int)2, framerate=(fraction)25/1, coded-picture-structure=(string)frame, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)baseline, level=(string)3.1, codec_data=(buffer)0142c01fffe200142742c01f898a300a00b74d408080ad878442334000186742c01f0fd91f888884000003000400000300c83c60c9200100066887cb83cb20 not accepted   {"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK", "caller": "../gst/gstpad.c:5819", "object": "video"}
2024-07-12T14:55:33.924Z        DEBUG   egress  [gst warning] gst_pad_query_accept_caps_default: caps: video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, width=(int)2, height=(int)2, framerate=(fraction)25/1, coded-picture-structure=(string)frame, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)baseline, level=(string)3.1, codec_data=(buffer)0142c01fffe200142742c01f898a300a00b74d408080ad878442334000186742c01f0fd91f888884000003000400000300c83c60c9200100066887cb83cb20 were not compatible with: EMPTY {"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK", "caller": "../gst/gstpad.c:3266", "object": "video_0"}
2024-07-12T14:55:33.924Z        DEBUG   egress  [gst warning] pre_eventfunc_check: caps video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, width=(int)2, height=(int)2, framerate=(fraction)25/1, coded-picture-structure=(string)frame, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)baseline, level=(string)3.1, codec_data=(buffer)0142c01fffe200142742c01f898a300a00b74d408080ad878442334000186742c01f0fd91f888884000003000400000300c83c60c9200100066887cb83cb20 not accepted   {"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK", "caller": "../gst/gstpad.c:5819", "object": "video"}
 2024-07-12T14:55:33.956Z        INFO    egress  sdk/appwriter.go:243    writer finished {"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK", "trackID": "TR_VCcoyq66v5r79s", "kind": "video", "sampleDuration": "36.333333ms", "avgDrift": "253.039µs", "maxDrift": "953.447µs", "packetLoss": "0.00%"}
2024-07-12T14:55:33.957Z        INFO    egress  pipeline/controller.go:261      Stopping the pipeline   {"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK"}
2024-07-12T14:55:33.957Z        DEBUG   egress  pipeline/controller.go:451      sending EOS     {"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK"}
2024-07-12T14:55:33.957Z        DEBUG   egress  [gst warning] gst_base_src_loop: error: Internal data stream error.     {"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK", "caller": "../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c:3175", "object": "app_TR_VCcoyq66v5r79s"}
2024-07-12T14:55:33.957Z        DEBUG   egress  [gst warning] gst_base_src_loop: error: streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4){"nodeID": "NE_TGmboxK5ZYhs", "handlerID": "EGH_M2wYqAbMj9MP", "clusterID": "", "egressID": "EG_ZzkiqYhMRfUK", "caller": "../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c:3175", "object": "app_TR_VCcoyq66v5r79s"}

I need to handle the gst.MessageEOS message to stop the egress process gracefully. Here's the relevant part of my messageWatch function and the handleEOSMessage function I've implemented:
func (c *Controller) messageWatch(msg *gst.Message) bool {
    var err error
    switch msg.Type() {
    case gst.MessageEOS:
        logger.Infow("EOS received")
        if !c.BaseConfig.UseFileStorage {
            if sink := c.getCloudSink(); sink != nil {
                // the timestamp in nanoseconds when recording is ended.
                sink.UpdateEndTime(c.src.GetEndedAt())
            }
        }
        c.p.Stop()
        return false
    case gst.MessageWarning:
        err = c.handleMessageWarning(msg.ParseWarning())
    case gst.MessageError:
        err = c.handleMessageError(msg.ParseError())
    case gst.MessageStateChanged:
        c.handleMessageStateChanged(msg)
    case gst.MessageElement:
        err = c.handleMessageElement(msg)
    }
    if err != nil {
        if c.Debug.EnableProfiling {
            c.uploadDebugFiles()
        }
        c.OnError(err)
        return false
    }

    return true
}

func (c *Controller) handleMessageError(gErr *gst.GError) error {
    element, name, message := parseDebugInfo(gErr)

    switch {
    case element == elementGstRtmp2Sink:
        if strings.HasPrefix(gErr.Error(), "Connection error") && !c.eos.IsBroken() {
            // try reconnecting
            ok, err := c.streamBin.ResetStream(name, gErr)
            if err != nil {
                logger.Errorw("failed to reset stream", err)
            } else if ok {
                return nil
            }
        }

        // remove sink
        url, err := c.streamBin.GetStreamUrl(name)
        if err != nil {
            logger.Warnw("rtmp output not found", err, "url", url)
            return err
        }

        return c.removeSink(context.Background(), url, gErr)

    case element == elementGstAppSrc:
        if message == msgStreamingNotNegotiated {
            // send eos to app src
            logger.Debugw("streaming stopped", "name", name)
            c.src.(*source.SDKSource).StreamStopped(name)
            return nil
        }

    case element == elementSplitMuxSink:
        // We sometimes get GstSplitMuxSink errors if send EOS before the first media was sent to the mux
        if message == msgMuxer {
            if c.eos.IsBroken() {
                logger.Debugw("GstSplitMuxSink failure after sending EOS")
                return nil
            }
        }
    }

    // input failure or file write failure. Fatal
    err := errors.ErrGstPipelineError(gErr)
    logger.Errorw(gErr.Error(), errors.New(message), "element", name)
    return err
}

